# JW Player hide full screen button

Tags: android, jwplayer

does someone has experience with the JWPlayer configuration on Android? 
I'm trying to hide the **`full-screen button`** from the controllers, The only thing that I succeeded is to remove all the controllers at once - `setControls(false)`

I already read every post on StackOverflow but with no luck. 
Hope someone can help me with this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, finally I found a solution. So I'll share it here for those who need it.

To remove the **full-screen button**, we need to use a custom CSS file and add a new `Skin` to our player:

```
SkinConfig skin = new SkinConfig.Builder()
        .url("https://s3.amazonaws.com/qa.jwplayer.com/~hyunjoo/android/css/hide-fullscreen.css")
        .name("hide-fullscreen")
        .build();

PlayerConfig config = new PlayerConfig.Builder()
        .autostart(true)
        .skinConfig(skin)
        .build();

mPlayerView.setup(config);
```

The CSS file should look like this:

```
.jw-icon-fullscreen{
    display: none !important;
}
```

Hope this will help others.